# The datetimepicker does not properly filter datagridview data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I face a bug that causes the filter work improperly - that is, when I change the value in datetimepicker then datagridview becomes empty

The code that I use is:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Expenses
                                .Where(x => x.Period == dateTimePicker1.Value)
                                .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to use >= or <= instead of == ??. Period may never have the value of DatePicker

Comment: What kind of thing is contained in the `Period` field in your database, exactly? What is its data type? Whatever it is, by using == you're probably restricting it so it's very unlikely it ever matches anything, especially if there's a time component involved in either the DB field or the datetimepicker value, or both - is it really going to match to the exact second? Normally a date filter is used to filter so that all dates before or after the selected date are displayed, rather than an exact match. You might also want to consider stripping the time component from both fields before comparing

Comment: If the *query* doesn't return anything, the grid will be empty. That's not a bug in DateTimePicker. What is `Period` and what is the value returned by `dateTimePicker1`? I suspect you are trying to load data for a single date but `Period` is a `DateTime`

Comment: Is `db.Expenses` have period that you selected in `datetimepicker`?

Comment: @ershoaib it seems fairly clear from the description that it doesn't! otherwise the query would return results. What's more interesting is a) what is the OP's actual intended functionality, and b) what are the exact contents of the fields and in what format.

Comment: @apomene, I have done as you said just changed == to <= but now there are data created today and when I choose today's date then all data is returned rather than today's data only

Comment: @mir 433, which format did u used for `Period` to save date in database and which datatype did u used?

Comment: @ershoaib, datetime2 is used

Comment: @mir433 in that case, if you want to filter to just a specific day using ==, you need to strip the time components from both your period and datetimepicker variables before you compare them. It's likely you're trying to compare today at midnight to, say, today at 13:00. It won't match. Like I said before, compare the Date part only. This is why we were asking for specific examples of the content of your fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may it help you

```
 private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Expenses
                     .Where(x => x.Period.Day == dateTimePicker1.Value.Day && 
                                 x.Period.Month == dateTimePicker1.Value.Month &&  
                                 x.Period.Year == dateTimePicker1.Value.Year)
                     .ToList();    
       //OR


       dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Expenses
                     .Where(x => x.Period.Date == dateTimePicker1.Value.Date)
                     .ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I think you can just remove the first option, there's no reason to ever choose that over the second one.

Comment: @ershoaib, thank you a lot for your attention and help. All works ok

Comment: Glad to hear you have get rid from your problem :)

Comment: @ADyson, the first case is best when user have to select only day or month or year or any combination of those,  then he simply remove or add any of condition that he needed from `Where` clause :)

Comment: @ershoaib the question and comments make clear that the exact day must be matched. There's no ambiguity, we know they don't want to just match the year or month. For matching the day you would need all 3 of year, month and day combined, which are provided anyway by the .Date shortcut. So I fail to see the point of it in this scenario. It's just a longer way of doing the same thing.

Comment: @ADyson,, you are absolutely right here, but any other user see this answer and if he/she need to select record with any combination of above then its useful for him/her. anyways I'll change the sequence of both, and thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly it is including the time in the comparison. Comparing the date only will solve it.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = Expenses
             .Where(x => x.Period.Date == dateTimePicker1.Value.Date)
             .ToList();
```

Comment: wouldn't it need to be `x.Period.Date` as well, to be certain? Do that and you get my upvote.

Comment: not if the time part is not stored in the database, .Date will return a DateTime with the time part set to 00:00:00

Comment: "not if the time part is not stored in the database" we don't know that for sure, as OP hasn't answered any of our questions about it. Best to be safe, since we know this code only wants to compare dates, why not give 100% certainty. If you don't want to update your answer to that effect, I can write my own version.